# Change window size when opening pdf from archive manager

Tags: pdf, archive

On Ubuntu 20.04, when I open a pdf file directly from the archive manager when it is part of a zip file, the document viewer always displays that pdf file in a small window. I would like it to open by default in a maximized window. The document viewer is whatever is delivered by default in Ubuntu 20.04 fresh install.
If I open the pdf from the Files manager (Nautilus) using the document viewer—NOT from the archive manager—then document viewer opens by default in a maximized window.
Changing the window size of document viewer has no impact on the small, default window size when opening from archive manager.
I though perhaps there would be a .desktop file that controls the behavior, but I cannot determine if this is so. Nor can I find any place where preferences for either of the two applications are set.
Bottom line: how can I change the default window size to maximize when opening a pdf file using document viewer from within archive manager?

Answer (score 3):

Evince appears to "remember" window sizes on a per file base. It is all very obscure and there is, frustratingly, little control on the window size.

*Caveat* The following options will act on all new Evince windows, not only those opened from an archive as asked.

**Maximize using Devilspie**

I use [Devilspie2](https://www.nongnu.org/devilspie2/) to ensure that each Evince window (whether the PDF is in an archive or not) is maximized on opening. This is a little (and unfortunately old, unmaintained and poorly documented) daemon program. It watches when a new window is created. If the window matches a criterion  (e.g. it is an Evince window), then it will apply the rule you defined for these types of windows (i.e., the window is maximized).

• You can install Devilspie2 with the command `sudo apt install devilspie2`.

• You need to create a configuration file `~/.config/devilspie2/devilspie2.lua` to define the rules.

This is my rule for Evince windows:

```
--Evince Document Viewer

if (not string.match(get_window_property("_NET_WM_STATE"),"_NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_PAGER") and get_application_name() == "Document Viewer" and get_window_name() ~= "Open Document" and get_window_name() ~= "Print" and get_window_name() ~= "Save As…" and get_window_name() ~= "Properties") then
   maximize();
end
```

The match criterion is rather complicated. It ensures that open and save dialogs, and PDF annotations, are not matched: for example, you do not want a maximized yellow note when you open one.

The action is very simple: maximize the window.

• For this to be enabled when you login, add devilspie to your autostart program. I found I need some delay for it to work, so my autostart command reads:

```
sh -c "sleep 8 && devilspie2 &"
```

**Full screen via Evince command line option**

Unfortunately, Evince has no command line option to start it maximized. However, there is a command line option to start it full screen. If that would be acceptable, you could launch Evince with the `-f` option. To achieve that, edit the `.desktop` launcher for Evince.

Comment: I ended up adding the -f parameter to the .desktop file.
Next, I opened a pdf file in that way pressed ESC and then resized the window. Then I removed the -f parameter.
The next time I opened a pdf from an archive, it opened in that new size of window - something that was NOT happening previously.

Answer (score 3):

The workaround I found helpful is, when the document opens unmaximized, press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow Key</kbd> on your keyboard. This key combination maximizes the window.

Answer (score 3):

The following two commands, executed in the terminal, work for me on Ubuntu 20.04 with Evince 3.36.10:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Evince.Default window-ratio '(1920, 1080)'
gsettings set org.gnome.Evince.Default sizing-mode 'fit-page'
```

In the place of `1920, 1080`, put in your screen size. After the first launch of Evince after that, it rewrites that ratio to something else (that still works).

Comment: Looks like a great trick.  Unfortunately it doesn't work (for me) on 22.04 (Wayland).  This is a deployment that was upgraded from 21.10, which didn't suffer from this issue...

Comment: @sxc731 This is a bug in 22.04.  The fix has been tested and should be released soon.  See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1969896

Comment: worked for me, 22.04 Wayland

Comment: It doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04