# Ubuntu 22.04 evince "Save Current Settings as Default" not working

Tags: 22.04, evince

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 and already tried the option "Save Current Settings as Default" in Evince.

This setting seems to work only for the already opened pdf files, not for the new ones.

Steps:

- open a pdf with evince
- maximize the window
- set "Save Current Settings as Default"
- reopen it: it opens maximized
- open a different pdf: the window isn't maximized

Evince has had this problem for at least 3 years. Why is it still not solved? It's so annoying to manually maximize all new opened pdf...

Thanks

Comment: Extremely irritating and frustrating indeed, that in Evince a default size and position of new documents (and documents you did not open for a long time) cannot be controlled. The problem is there for far more than 3 years...

Comment: If you use xorg, the devilspie2 rule https://askubuntu.com/a/1308253/558158 works very well. That will not work on Wayland.

Comment: @vanadium thanks, but I don't want to fix that stupid bug with an extra package installation... it's a shame that such bug is still here