# How to resize the icons in file browser in Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

I don't know exactly if the problem is related to Nautilus or Ubuntu itself.
The files in the opening/saving files window are too small and i could not find a way to resize it.

[image]

Comment: You could try `ctrl++`.

Comment: I've tried. It doesn't work.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're using. That said, from what I can see in the image, you're in List View in Nautilus/Files. You need to switch to Grid View to see the larger icons. Also--regardless of view--you have the option to change icon size from the Main Menu (as @mikewhatever points out via the key combo).

Comment: see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1399130/1698042

Comment: @TalaatEtman The answer you linked to is not related in any way. You may have provided a different link than the one you intended.

Comment: is this problem in all applications (ex: try to save/open file by text editor) or just in your internet explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no.

The GTK3 file picker is the file dialog you see. GTK file pickers have always been rather limited. For one, there is only a list view, no icon view, and there is no way to adapt the size of the icons.

The idea is, in the future, to [effectively also use the file manager nautilus](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/5590) as the file picker. Until then, we need to continue clunking around a little bit in this respect, like the past 30 years. This is where the KDE desktop apparently did a much better job.

Comment: Thank you for a clear explanation of both the question and the problem. Indeed, my suggestion does not work in the file picker.